# dynamically update select option on keyup in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

[FIDDLE LNK](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/8Lcq62mn/16/) for my 3 select option. What i want to do is when on document.ready the `Continent` will be `populated` and then the `country` of the active continent will be load on the `country` and then the `city` will be loaded depending on the `country`.

Also i have input text when the user type into the textbox that will be the value that will appear on the select as a selected option.

Comment: First of all you have duplicate id's on select and input, that will not work. For example http://jsfiddle.net/8Lcq62mn/11/ change select box id to continentselect to fill continents.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit button click code, you have to append new option to the drop down instead of updating the value. So instead of this:

```
$('#continentselect').val(continent);
$('#countryselect').val(country);
$('#cityselect').val(city);
```

Try this:

```
$('#continentselect').append('<option>' + continent + '</option>');
$('#countryselect').append('<option>' + country + '</option>');
$('#cityselect').val('<option>' + city + '</option>');
```

Also you need to update your js arrays i.e. `country`, `continent` and `city` with the newly entered values from the text-boxes.